# convert list to string in data.frame

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe

I have the following data.frame, with ccodealp_year being of class "list"

```
value.change    ccodealp_year   
-2.0            COD08   
5.5             LBR08   
-3.0            NER99   
-2.0            c("AGO99", "COL96") 
-1.0            c("GNB03", "SEN09")
```

I would like to 'convert' the content of ccodealp_year into one string (per row).
The problem I have concerns these values with more than one list entry: c("AGO99", "COL96") 
and c("GNB03", "SEN09"); what I am aiming at is to get entries of class character which read as

```
ccodealp_year   
COD08   
LBR08   
NER99   
AGO99, COL96
GNB03, SEN09
```

So far I figured out

```
e$ccodealp_year.x  <- paste0(" ",unlist(e$ccodealp_year), collapse="")
```

which, however, puts all entries of ccodealp_year into each row.

```
[1] " COD08 LBR08 NER99 AGO99 COL96 GNB03 SEN09"
[2] " COD08 LBR08 NER99 AGO99 COL96 GNB03 SEN09"
[3] " COD08 LBR08 NER99 AGO99 COL96 GNB03 SEN09"
[4] " COD08 LBR08 NER99 AGO99 COL96 GNB03 SEN09"
[5] " COD08 LBR08 NER99 AGO99 COL96 GNB03 SEN09"
```

Do I have to convert them into a string and then remove "c", the bracket and hyphens with something like gsub? Or is there a more direct way? I would have assumed this is rather straightforward but unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work. Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe something like `sapply(yourdf$ccodealp_year, paste, collapse = ", ")`? Can you post the output of `head(yourdf)` (replacying "yourdf" with the actual name of your `data.frame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to generate the same printed output as you, but from your description, it sounds like your data is in the following format

```
dd<-data.frame(value.change=c(-2,5.5,-3,-2,-1))
dd$ccodealp_year <- list("COD08","LBR08", "NER99", c("AGO99", "COL96"), c("GNB03", "SEN09") )

dd
#   value.change ccodealp_year
# 1         -2.0         COD08
# 2          5.5         LBR08
# 3         -3.0         NER99
# 4         -2.0  AGO99, COL96
# 5         -1.0  GNB03, SEN09

str(dd)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ value.change : num  -2 5.5 -3 -2 -1
#  $ ccodealp_year:List of 5
#   ..$ : chr "COD08"
#   ..$ : chr "LBR08"
#   ..$ : chr "NER99"
#   ..$ : chr  "AGO99" "COL96"
#   ..$ : chr  "GNB03" "SEN09"
```

so even though when they print they look like sigle values, they are in fact vectors. To convert to concatendated strings, you can do

```
dd$ccodealp_year <- sapply(dd$ccodealp_year, paste, collapse=",")

dd
#   value.change ccodealp_year
# 1         -2.0         COD08
# 2          5.5         LBR08
# 3         -3.0         NER99
# 4         -2.0   AGO99,COL96
# 5         -1.0   GNB03,SEN09

str(dd)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ value.change : num  -2 5.5 -3 -2 -1
#  $ ccodealp_year: chr  "COD08" "LBR08" "NER99" "AGO99,COL96" ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this might be a case of `list of lists`

```
 ccodealp_year=list( "COD08", "LBR08", "NER99", list(c("AGO99", "COL96")),list(c("GNB03", "SEN09")))
  dat <- data.frame(value.change=c(-2.0, 5.5, -3, -2, -1), I(ccodealp_year))

   dat
  #  value.change ccodealp_year
  #1         -2.0         COD08
  #2          5.5         LBR08
  #3         -3.0         NER99
  #4         -2.0  c("AGO99....
  #5         -1.0  c("GNB03....


  dat[,2] <- sapply(do.call(`c`,dat[,2]), paste, collapse=", ")
  dat
```